# How to append a char into array and tokenize it C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

In my main function I am using `letter(ch)`. I am trying to get some letter characters to become a string or token. Before using the `append` function it would just print all the characters out.

```
//output  
000: u  
001: s  
002: e  
003: .  
004: s  
005: y  
006: s  
007: t  
008: e  
009: m  
010: .  
011: i  
012: o  
013: ;
```

I found an appending function that gets the letter characters into the array, but it prints out like a pyramid. How do I get the last result when it's done appending, and use the `'\0'` to split it? Shouldn't it have already split it by the initial `'\0'` in the `append` function? Am I approaching this in the right direction? Is there something I'm missing in order for the split after the null?

```
//output   
000: u  
001: us  
002: use  
003: .  
004: uses  
005: usesy  
006: usesys  
007: usesyst  
008: usesyste  
009: usesystem  
010: .  
011: usesystemi  
012: usesystemio  
013: ;
```

```
//main.c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ch_type.h"


FILE *file;
char line[400];
int line_num;
char  ch;

void append(char* line, char ch)
{
    int length = strlen(line);
    line[length] = ch;
    line[length + 1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    file = fopen("source.txt", "r");

    while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if(space(ch))
        {
            printf(" %03d: %c\n", line_num++, ch);
        }
        if(letter(ch))
        {
            append(line, ch);
            printf(" %03d: %s\n", line_num++, line);
        }
        if(separator(ch))
        {
            printf(" %03d: %c\n", line_num++, ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
//ch_type.h

int space(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == ' '));
}

int letter(int ch)
{
    return (((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) || (ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'));
}


int separator(int ch)
{
    return ((ch == '#') || (ch == '(') || (ch == ')') || (ch == '{') || (ch == '}') || (ch == '[') || (ch == ']')
        || (ch == '<') || (ch == '>') || (ch == '.') || (ch == ',') || (ch == ':') || (ch == ';'));
}
```

Comment: Going forward, please post text of input/output instead of pictures of input/output. That allows others to verify your results and where you have 200-300 characters of storage, your second image alone `aOXPB.png` requires `13534` bytes to store `:)`

Comment: Will do. I did not realize that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `line` when you enter `if(space(ch))` or `if(separator(ch))` instead of after finding each character of a line. After that, set the first byte to `0` so the string is "empty" again:

```
        if(space(ch))
        {
            printf(" %03d: %s\n", line_num++, line);
            line[0] = '\0';
            printf(" %03d: %c\n", line_num++, ch);
        }
        if(letter(ch))
        {
            append(line, ch);
        }
        if(separator(ch))
        {
            printf(" %03d: %s\n", line_num++, line);
            line[0] = '\0';
            printf(" %03d: %c\n", line_num++, ch);
        }
```

You should probably also prepend `else` to both `if(letter(ch))` and `if(separator(ch))`. This might improve performance a little since none of these conditions overlap.

Note that this is assuming that separators and spaces don't go together, but that shouldn't necessarily matter.

Here is a simplified version of this that doesn't require duplicated code:

```
        if(letter(ch))
        {
            append(line, ch);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" %03d: %s\n", line_num++, line);
            line[0] = '\0';
        }
        if(space(ch) || separator(ch))
        {
            printf(" %03d: %c\n", line_num++, ch);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the actual letters as a whole? Right now the printf before the null prints the previous letters, etc. before nulling it. But it gets a little tricky in formatting when there isn't letters.  For simplicity sake I didn't add the number(ch), operators(ch), etc to the code above when I asked. It seems its assumed that the letter chars will always before the others? Starts getting funny with space(ch) and neli(ch) aka  '\n'. I tried using a strcmp function to compare the letters to another array with inialized keywords which worked but was duplicated.

Comment: @Lordravenblack You can ask another question and provide a link to this one to provide context.